# Using inverse operations to justify a proof in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Hello I am working on a proof which includes a $-$ operator and I am trying to justify it by bringing the value to the other side of the equation. If 'add' the value both sides am I just including the union of the value?

The equation I'm trying to justify is $A - (B ∩ A) = A - B$.

Comment: Not very clear... The analogy with algebraic operations can be misleading but e.g. if $A=B$, then $A \cap C = B \cap C$ and similar.

Comment: Are you meaning something like $A - B + B$? If so, what is "+"?

Comment: An alternate strategy is to rephrase this: prove that $x \in A$ and $x \notin B \cap A$ if and only if $x \in A$ and $x \notin B$.

Answer (score 0):

$-$ and $+$ aren't inverses of one another in this case, so you cannot derive $A-B=C$ by showing that $A=C+B$. For example, if $C\subseteq A$ is non-empty then $A-A\neq C$, but $A=C+A$. You can always go *forwards* though. If $A=B$ then $A+C=B+C$ and $A-C=B-C$.